# Cannot decrypt AES-256 GCM with Java

Tags: java, node.js, aes, aes-gcm

I have a node module that can both encrypt and decrypt with AES-256 GCM. Now I am also trying to decrypt with Java whatever the node module encrypts, but I keep getting a AEADBadTagException.

I have tested the node module by itself and can confirm that it works as intended. I know that Java assumes the authentication tag is the last part of the message, so I ensured that the tag is the last thing appended in the node module.

Right now I'm just testing with the word, "hello". This is the encrypted message from node:
`Q10blKuyyYozaRf0RVYW7bave8mT5wrJzSdURQQa3lEqEQtgYM3ss825YpCQ70A7hpq5ECPafAxdLMSIBZCxzGbv/Cj4i6W4JCJXuS107rUy0tAAQVQQA2ZhbrQ0gNV9QA==`

The salt is not really being used right now because I am trying to keep things simple for testing purposes

Node module:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var encrypt = function(masterkey, plainText) {
    // random initialization vector
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);

    // random salt
    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(64);

    var key = masterkey;

    // AES 256 GCM Mode
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);

    // encrypt the given text
    var encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(plainText, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);

    // extract the auth tag
    var tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

    return Buffer.concat([salt, iv, encrypted, tag]).toString('base64');
};

var decrypt = function(masterkey, encryptedText) {
    // base64 decoding
    var bData = new Buffer(encryptedText, 'base64');

    // convert data to buffers
    var salt = bData.slice(0, 64);
    var iv = bData.slice(64, 76);
    var tag = bData.slice(bData.length - 16, bData.length);
    var text = bData.slice(76, bData.length - 16);

    var key = masterkey;

    // AES 256 GCM Mode
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(tag);

    // encrypt the given text
    var decrypted = decipher.update(text, 'binary', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');

    return decrypted;
};

module.exports = {
    encrypt: encrypt,
    decrypt: decrypt
}
```

Java Class:
The main method is just there for testing right now and will be removed later.

```
package decryption;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class DecryptAES256 {

    private static String salt;
    private static byte[] ivBase64;
    private static String base64EncryptedText;
    private static String key;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "123456789aabbccddeefffffffffffff";
        String sourceText = "Q10blKuyyYozaRf0RVYW7bave8mT5wrJzSdURQQa3lEqEQtgYM3ss825YpCQ70A7hpq5ECPafAxdLMSIBZCxzGbv/Cj4i6W4JCJXuS107rUy0tAAQVQQA2ZhbrQ0gNV9QA==";
        System.out.println(decrypt(key, sourceText));
    }

    public static String decrypt(String masterkey, String encryptedText) {
        byte[] parts = encryptedText.getBytes();
        salt = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 0, 64));
        ivBase64 = Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 64, 76);
        ivBase64 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ivBase64);
        base64EncryptedText = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 76, parts.length));
        key = masterkey;
        byte[] decipheredText = decodeAES_256_CBC();
        return new String(decipheredText);
    }

    private static byte[] decodeAES_256_CBC() {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            byte[] text = base64EncryptedText.getBytes();
            GCMParameterSpec params = new GCMParameterSpec(128, ivBase64, 0, ivBase64.length);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, params);
            return cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(text));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to decrypt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For AES encryption you need to download and replace unlimited policy for JDK8. You can download it using www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html link. Then you have to make replacement at the following path : java/jdk/jre/lib/security

Comment: @NisheshPratap I have already done that

Comment: If you want to avoid the Oracle export regulations limitations, you can look at the BouncyCastle Java library.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo Trying to avoid third party stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception thrown is normal, you have 2 problems in your Java code:

1- **your AES key is not decoded correctly**: it is wrapped in hexadecimal representation and you decode it as if it was not. You need to convert it from the hexadecimal representation to bytes, when calling `SecretKeySpec()`.

Replace the following line:

```
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
```

By this one:

```
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray()), "AES");
```

Note that to get access to the Hex class, you need to import `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` in your class file and include the corresponding Apache **commons-codec** library in your project.

2- **you split your base64 cipher text before having converted it to base64**, this is not the correct order to do things:

At the start of your `decrypt()` method, you need to **first** call `Base64.getDecoder().decode()` on your cipher text (`sourceText`) before splitting it into the corresponding fields.

If you want an example of using AES-256-GCM in Java, you can look at the following example I had written some months ago: https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/kif-idp-client

The source code to encrypt and decrypt is in the following file: https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/kif-idp-client/blob/master/src/kif/libfc/Tools.java

See the methods named `encodeGCM()` and `decodeGCM()`.

Those methods are called by the main class here: https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/kif-idp-client/blob/master/src/kif/libfc/CommandLine.java

Comment: I know the key looks hex encoded and this is my bad for not clarifying, but the key is in plain text. As for the second point, that solved it, thanks!

Comment: Could you also take a look at this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307621/cannot-decrypt-long-aes-256-gcm-message-with-java
The same issue comes up with longer messages, but short messages decrypt just fine.